# Error in Android Developers Tutorial?

Tags: android

I am working my way through some of the android developers tutorial, specifically the Gallery View Widget located [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) I have made it through stages 1 and 2 yet I seem to be getting 3 errors and I cannot fathom what it is I have done wrong, as I have copied and pasted the code direct from the tutorial and made one change to the code, that being R.layout.events instead of R.layout.main

Here is the code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Events extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.events);

    Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
    gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter (this));

    gallery.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(Events.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}}
```

The errors that I am getting are as follows:

ImageAdapter cannot be resolved to a type   line 18 Java Problem
OnItemClickListener cannot be resolved to a type    line 20 Java Problem

The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type AdapterView is not applicable for the arguments (new OnItemClickListener(){})      line 20  Java Problem

Any advice or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: We can't actually see what errors you're getting. Seems like it would be easier to help if we could.

Comment: Sorry, I realized this post, posting and was adding them in whilst you was commenting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong listener type.  It should be View.OnClickListener.

```
gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { ....
```

Or use setOnItemClickListener...

```
gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { ...
```

Comment: Thank you as well, that also fixed those specific errors. Is it standard for Android Dev to have errors in their tutorials?

Answer (score 6):

The ImageAdapter is a custom BaseAdapter defined further in the post, at point 6.

> A custom BaseAdapter called ImageAdapter is instantiated (...)

And at point 6:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter { //(...)
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I feel kinda dumb for not going all the way through now